# Escaped curly brace in string.format gets lost. Possible C# bug?

Tags: c#, escaping, string-formatting

I have this MSVC 2012 MCVE:

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string [] args)
        {
            string result = string.Format(@"{{{0:G};{1:G}}}", foo(), bar());
            Console.WriteLine(result);
        }

        private static string foo() { return "foo"; }
        private static string bar() { return "bar"; }
    }
}
```

Expected output: `{foo;bar}`

Result: `{foo;bar`

Changing the format string to `@"{{{0:G};{1:G} }}"`  [adding a space] produces the correct output. Is it a possible bug or why is the escaped closing curly brace not displayed?

Comment: Soner Gönül has give you a good answer. The problem is that the data is  interpreted sequentially or evaluated  sequentially without tree or expressions. I do not know if Microsoft just have find the easist way to solve the problem or is there are any other reasons. Maybe a data scientist can answer this quesiton.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [Escaping Braces section on Composite Formatting](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/txafckwd(v=vs.110).aspx);

> Opening and closing braces are interpreted as starting and ending a
>   format item. Consequently, you must use an escape sequence to display
>   a literal opening brace or closing brace. Specify two opening braces
>   ("{{") in the fixed text to display one opening brace ("{"), or two
>   closing braces ("}}") to display one closing brace ("}"). Braces in a
>   format item are interpreted sequentially in the order they are
>   encountered. Interpreting nested braces is not supported.
>
> **The way escaped braces are interpreted can lead to unexpected results**.
>   For example, consider the format item `"{{{0:D}}}"`, which is intended
>   to display an opening brace, a numeric value formatted as a decimal
>   number, and a closing brace. However, the format item is actually
>   interpreted in the following manner:
>
> - The first two opening braces ("{{") are escaped and yield one opening brace.
> - The next three characters ("{0:") are interpreted as the start of a format item.
> - The next character ("D") would be interpreted as the Decimal standard numeric format specifier, but the next two escaped braces
>     ("}}") yield a single brace. Because the resulting string ("D}") is
>     not a standard numeric format specifier, the resulting string is
>     interpreted as a custom format string that means display the literal
>     string "D}".
> - The last brace ("}") is interpreted as the end of the format item.
> - The final result that is displayed is the literal string, "{D}". The numeric value that was to be formatted is not displayed.
>
> **One way to write your code to avoid misinterpreting escaped braces and
>   format items is to format the braces and format item separately**.

So you should use it as;

```
string result = string.Format(@"{0}{1:G};{2:G}{3}", "{", "foo", "bar", "}");
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. How ever, I consider it as a bug because some C# builder have been lazy. There is **not any** reason the C# compiler acts like this.

Comment: @AlBundy I doubt that for "bug" since it's written in documentation but those braces _might_ confuse the lexer/tokenizer. This could be the reason in my opition. I will ask to .NET Team this issue asap.

Comment: You can "*legalize*" a bug adding it into the documentation. Apple is the master of this universe regarding this [you hold it wrong - the "bug" with the antenna]. Anyway, I upvoted your answer so I accept it of course. It was just my own private opinion.